# pywhatkit library installation error related to display

Tags: python, python-3.x, whatsapp

I am trying to install pywhatkit & its giving me error related to display

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-c3e3747f918e> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # importing module
----> 2 import pywhatkit as pwk

4 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    678         except KeyError:
    679             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 680             raise KeyError(key) from None
    681         return self.decodevalue(value)
    682 

KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

Please help

I am using pywhatkit for sending messages on whatsapp its not working because of display error.

Comment: Please show the whole traceback, and also format it properly.

Comment: exception is thrown from module: os .. and it could be that it is trying to read DISPLAY environment variable. Since PyWhatKit seems to depend on pyautogui - problem could be that you are trying to run on headless environment or without X server or you are ssh'ing into remote machine and not using display forwarding..

Comment: Also, if you are running this on some notebook via webbrowser - pywhatkit probably wont be very helpful..

Comment: Run from command line. Also, the 4 frames missing are important.  Then if it still doesn't work set *env var* `DISPLAY=":0.0"` before importing.